# Tweepy twitter bot replies to new requests

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm looking for a way to stop my Twitter bot, [HappyBot](https://twitter.com/1happybot), from replying to each user who has tweeted at it, and instead to only reply to new tweets since the last time the code was run. For example, if I tweeted the bot at 13:00 it would reply at 13:00 but if I tweeted it again at 14:00 it would reply to both the 13:00 and the 14:00 tweet. The code I run currently:

```
twts = api.search(q="@1happybot make me happy")

t = ['@1happybot make me happy',
     '@1happybot Make me happy!',
     '@1happybot make me happy.',
     'Make me happy @1happybot',
     'make me happy @1happybot']

for s in twts:
    for i in t:
        if i == s.text:
            sn = s.user.screen_name
            m = "@%s Don't worry, be happy!" % (sn)
            s = api.update_status(m, s.id)
            print ('yes')
```

Any solutions, ideas or jumping off points would be greatly appreciated. Hope everything is clear.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to get mentions using tweepy except using a search like you're doing, and [automatically replying based on a search may violate Twitter's ToS](https://support.twitter.com/articles/76915#replies-mentions). You should confirm with their support that it is OK to do this (they will probably say yes).

Answer (score 3):

The solution I offer here is quick & dirty, but it should work. Basically, it stores the value of the last tweet you replied to in a text file to ensure persistence when your code stops, and reloads it when your code is called. With the "since" option, it will only look for tweets older than those you have already replied to, and thus it will not find a tweet twice.

```
f = open("lastTweet.txt","r")
lastTweet = int(f.readline())
f.close()

twts = api.search("@1happybot make me happy since:"+str(lastTweet))

t = ['@1happybot make me happy',
     '@1happybot Make me happy!',
     '@1happybot make me happy.',
     'Make me happy @1happybot',
     'make me happy @1happybot']

for s in twts:
    for i in t:
        if i == s.text:
            sn = s.user.screen_name
            m = "@%s Don't worry, be happy!" % (sn)
            s = api.update_status(m, s.id)
            print ('yes')
            if s.id > lastId:
                lastId = s.id
                f = open("lastTweet.txt","w")
                f.write(lastId)
                f.close()
```

Comment: Huh that's pretty interesting, thanks. I hadn't thought of a solution that way. It works well because it presumes that the code will be stopping and starting, which it will. I could use cron to call it every couple of minutes or so

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, could you please click the big checkbox to accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Which library are you using? My best guess is that whatever it is you are using will expose the JSON response that twitter returns. In this case you could try retrieving the creation date of the tweet. See https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets

```
s.created_at
```

That should give you the datetime string. Your code could also be a lot more pythonic. Take a look at:

```
TRIGGERS = ('@1happybot make me happy',
            '@1happybot Make me happy!',
            '@1happybot make me happy.',
            'Make me happy @1happybot',
            'make me happy @1happybot')

for tweet in tweets:
    if tweet.text in TRIGGERS:
        sn = tweet.user.screen_name
        status_msg = '@{} Don't worry, be happy!'.format(sn)
        api.update_status(status_msg, s.id)
        print ('yes')
```

Naming things is hard but we should try our best to be descriptive without being too verbose. Variable names should communicate their intent. Use conventions like "element in list" instead of looping through a list to see if an element is in it. Be consistent in your use of quotes. Single quotes were used for your list of strings but not in the status msg you were setting. Choose one, stick to it.

Are the values in TRIGGERS ever going to change? Use a non mutable type like a tuple if that is the case and communicate that intent of keeping it static by using all caps. Lots of little things. Highly recommend you read -> http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html